# Can I get GPS coordinates without internet?

Tags: gps, gsm

am I able to get GPS coordinates for my app with Google Maps API just with GPS and GSM (no mobile internet or Wi-Fi)?

Thank You!

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't found questions about gps coordinates. Just if GPS worked without GSM or Internet.

Comment: If this is a programming question, you can get more help on http://www.StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, of course... You don't even need GSM service to get GPS coordinates, as long as your device has a working GPS chipset.